# The curious case of toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really new to Jquery and was trying to figure out why my JQuery code that I got from another user will not work when I place the id attribute in the ol tag but works fine when the id attribute is placed in the nav tag. If some one can be so kind to explain this problem to me thanks.

HTML

```
    <nav id="cat">
      <ol>
        <li><a title="" href="#1">1;</a></li>
        <li><a title="" href="#2">2</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>

    <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
    <nav class="sub">
      <ol id="1">
        <li><a title="" href="">1a</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>

    <!-- WORKS -->
    <nav class="sub" id="2">
      <ol>
        <li><a title="" href="">2a</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
```

JQuery

```
    var $subs = $('.sub');
    $('#cat > ol > li > a').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href'),
        $target = $(href);
        $target.stop().slideToggle('slow');
        $subs.not($target).stop().slideUp('slow');
    });
```

Here is the fiddle
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/j95dfLxu/)

Comment: `$subs` is a collection of `<nav>` tags with the class `sub`. The `not($target)` function appears to be looking for `<nav class="sub"...>` with an ID (or rather, those without the specified ID). Without knowing exactly what is happening against what is expected to happen, it's difficult to tell if this is the cause or not.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `id=1` onto the child `ol` means that the ol is no longer also a `.sub`. you need to move both ids to the child `ol`s and then update the `$sub` selector to be `.sub > ol`

http://jsfiddle.net/41rh3n4w/

Comment: i think i was looking at the wrong `ol`. as @Eraph said, your problem is with $subs. i'll update my answer

Comment: This did not seem to work either thanks for the help though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/41rh3n4w/ this looks to be toggling, maybe im still misunderstanding

Comment: your code seems to be working fine but when I try it on my localhost nothing works.

Comment: something on your localhost, that's not in your example code?